# Docker Apache Container exist immediately (Build from Docker File) on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, dockerfile, containers

I have created a docker file and while i am building and runing the container the container exits immediately.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 as the base OS on which docker is installed.

My docker file contains the following

```
FROM ubuntu <br>
RUN apt-get update <br>
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y <br>
RUN apt-get install apache2-utils -y <br>
RUN apt-get clean <br>
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* <br>
EXPOSE 80 <br>
ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl"] <br>
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"] <br>
```

Command Used to build the image is :
`sudo docker build -t myimage` .

Command user to Run the Container is :

```
sudo docker run -it -p 80:80 myimage
```

Following output

```
sudo docker ps -a <br>
```

> CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND
>   CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS
>   NAMES 6b1891ac8195        myimage             "apache2ctl /usr/sbi…"
>   15 minutes ago      Exited (1) 15 minutes ago
>   infallible_williamson 
>  dc3cc1328508        5b5570dec3a9
>   "tail -f /dev/null /…"   17 minutes ago      Exited (1) 17 minutes ago
>   stoic_ganguly 
>  a67f5cb9f080        53a1c1ddc4fc        "tail -f
>   /dev/null /…"   18 minutes ago      Exited (1) 18 minutes ago
>   vibrant_grothendieck 
>  07fa216c6c00        b5d19c3240f7
>   "apache2ctl /usr/sbi…"   31 minutes ago      Exited (1) 31 minutes ago
>   keen_blackburn 
>  71d686cb0b8e        568c96482f1c
>   "apache2ctl /bin/sh …"   39 minutes ago      Exited (1) 38 minutes ago
>   happy_saha 
>  11e0abe7c2ec        d056b6f1d824        "apache2ctl
>   /bin/sh …"   40 minutes ago      Exited (1) 40 minutes ago
>   vibrant_kare 
>  17ed24e8eef4        d056b6f1d824        "apache2ctl
>   /bin/sh …"   3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago
>   gallant_dijkstra 
>  b1c6d9bf2765        d056b6f1d824
>   "apache2ctl /bin/sh …"   3 hours ago         Exited (1) 3 hours ago
>   elated_joliot

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Few things to correct in your Dockerfile**

> Use specific versions for your base images

`FROM ubuntu:18.04` **add specific version to your `FROM` images**, this helps to understand **what version of base image(`Ubuntu:18.04`) this Docker image is built with**.

> Combine multiple `RUN` commands

**Combine multiple `RUN` commands to single `RUN` command**, if possible, helps to reduce number of docker layers which in turn reduces the size of the image.

**Check Dockerfile best practices** - https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run

Change this from

```
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y 
RUN apt-get install apache2-utils -y
```

to

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 apache2-utils && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

> CMD correction

As you have already mentioned `apache2ctl` in your `ENTRYPOINT` **no need to mention it again in your `CMD`**. Your **command is interpreted as** `apache2ctl /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -DFOREGROUND`. Hence docker `run` command is failing.

So here is how your `Dockerfile` was modified:

```
$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y apache2 apache2-utils && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl"]
CMD ["-DFOREGROUND"]
```

Now **build Docker image** as you have done.

```
$ docker build -t myimage:1.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   38.3MB
Step 1/5 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> cf0f3ca922e0
Step 2/5 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y apache2 apache2-utils &&     apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2f47b3a5e735
Step 3/5 : EXPOSE 80
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5b395b19a0dc
Step 4/5 : ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> be1afc8d76c3
Step 5/5 : CMD ["-DFOREGROUND"]
 ---> Running in 3d0d78c566e2
Removing intermediate container 3d0d78c566e2
 ---> 00167996f7f3
Successfully built 00167996f7f3
Successfully tagged myimage:1.0
```

**Run the container in detached mode**, `-d`, as to run process in the background.

```
$ docker run -d -p 80:80 myimage:1.0
eccb77059f9ce8628e7a47d64adb9d20a3ca6cb3cecce06935b46eb13652b992


$ docker ps | grep eccb77
eccb77059f9c        myimage:1.0       "apache2ctl -DFOREGR…"   14 seconds ago      Up 12 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                     charming_payne

$ docker ps | grep eccb77
eccb77059f9c        myimage:1.0       "apache2ctl -DFOREGR…"   27 seconds ago      Up 25 seconds       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                     charming_payne

$ docker ps | grep eccb77
eccb77059f9c        myimage:1.0        "apache2ctl -DFOREGR…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp                     charming_payne
```

**Hit the URL with localhost and port 80**

```
$ curl http://localhost:80

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!--
    Modified from the Debian original for Ubuntu
    Last updated: 2016-11-16
    See: https://launchpad.net/bugs/1288690
  -->
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page: It works</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  * {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
```

**Also from the browser**

[image]